# Submit form with angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following **[Angular code](https://plnkr.co/edit/JnsfqhcC6yzlaLR3VcNa?p=preview)**

**controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {  
  var vm = this;  
  vm.job = null;  
  vm.create = function (job) {      
    vm.job = job;    
  }  
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">

  <span data-ng-bind="vm.job.position"></span>

  <form name="form" data-ng-submit="vm.create(vm.job)">

    <label for="position">Position</label>
    <input id="position" name="vm.job.position" type="text" data-ng-model="vm.job.position" />

    <button>Create</button>      

  </form>      

</div>
```

But when I submit the form I don't see the Position value.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because

1. You forgot to add ng-app to the body or html element
2. You're using angular 1.0.8, which is completely obsolete, and doesn't support `controller as`.

Note that you don't even need to submit, since the job you're binding is already `vm.job`. Your `create(vm.job)` method call does nothing: it assigns `vm.job` to `vm.job`.